# Model binding an entity without setters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view, model

In my domain I have entities that don't have setters on the properties (except for the odd special case). Therefore all values have to be passed in via the constructor.

Problem is, now that I'm using the domain entities as the model for my CREATE views, when the model binder tries to bind the form fields to the model, it's throwing a `No parameterless constructor defined for this object` error.

What would be the best way around this. The one's I can think of are:

1. Create a new model binder???
2. Create a mapper for each entity used in the view that converts a `FormCollection` to the entity.
3. Create a ViewModel representation of the entity and map it to the original entity class before sending out of MVC to my service layer.
4. Refactor the entities to include setters.

I don't really want to open up my entities by including setters. Does anybody have any tips? The easiest/cleanest way possible is ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest/reccommended/error-proof/easy-to-maintain way to do that is **3.Create a ViewModel**. ViewModel will have only the fields needed to create the view. You validate that, convert to Domain Models (maybe using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)) and send to service layer.